# Is this model linear function belongs to GLM models?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, least-squares, binary-data, link-function

In GLM, we assume that $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]=\mu(\beta^\top X)$ and $Y|X$ follows exponential family distribution. I am going to assume that the probability of success in the Bernoulli distribution is modeled as $\beta^\top X$. However, the issue is that because $\beta^\top X$ can take values less than 0 or greater than 1, I will use map $\mu(\beta^\top X)=0$ if $\beta^\top X<0$ and $\mu(\beta^\top X)=1$ if $\beta^\top X>1$. I am wondering if I use this modeling, I will still have a GLM model? Is the link function $g=\infty $ for $\beta^\top X<0$, $g=\text{identity}$ for $0\le\beta^\top \le 1$, and $g=1 $ for $\beta^\top X>1$?

If I use this definition, can I estimate parameters through OLS accurately?

Comment: Note that GLMs having their parameters estimated by minimizing the sum of squares is the exception, not the rule. Logistic regression, for instance, classically minimizes the log loss (equivalent to maximum likelihood estimation for the binomial likelihood).

Answer (score 0):

By setting $0$ and $1$ as bounds on the predictions, you’ve put yourself in a position where you do not have a linear model. Rather, your model is something along the lines of:

$$\mathbb E [Y\vert X=x]=
\min\{
\max\{
0, \beta^Tx
\}, 1
\}
$$

A linear probability model, which shoehorns the binary $0$$/$$1$ data into an ordinary least squares linear regression, does not have that $\min\max$ business. The linear probability model is an ordinary linear model.

Ultimately, you can do basically whatever you want and call it Amin’s estimator, and if you can prove that a bizarre technique unexpectedly has desirable properties, then maybe you have a paper for a top statistics journal like JASA. However, I would not expect the $\hat\beta$ estimate via either maximum likelihood or minimization of square loss in the above model to coincide with the parameter estimates from a true linear probability model (or a logistic or probit regression, for that matter).

Comment: The model *is* linear, as is manifest in the $\beta^\prime x$ term.  It's the *inverse link function* $g(t)=\min(\max(t,0),1)$ that is extraordinary.  Its lack of differentiability is a bit of a problem for finding solutions, especially with multiple regressors; but if one were truly in a situation where there are thresholds at which the probabilities will saturate at $0$ or $1$ exactly, it could be plausible.